# glossaries format removing hyperlink

Tags: glossaries

Tried including user-manual reading but...

```
\glsdisp[format=textbf]{arts:FourHorsemen}{Four Horsemen}
```

using

```
\usepackage[xindy={language=german,codepage=duden-utf8},
nonumberlist,
toc,
nopostdot,
style=altlist,
nogroupskip
]{glossaries}
\GlsSetXdyCodePage{duden-utf8}

\newglossary*{arts}{Kunst?}
...
\glsdisp[format=textbf]{arts:FourHorsemen}{Four Horsemen}
...
\printglossary[type=arts, nonumberlist=false, style=index]
```

Does remove the hyperlink from the page number at the glossary back into the text (the other, not formated bold entries still have their hyperlinks). Guess I am missing something trivial so after two hourse reading, searching and trying... please!

no MWE because because I guess that makes little sense with xindy and custom glossaries?

Comment: Try `format=hyperbf` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default format `glsnumberformat` includes a hyperlink (if enabled). If you change the format to `textbf` the hyperlink is lost. The `glossaries` package provides analogous formats to `textbf` etc called `hyperbf` etc that include a hyperlink. If you don't include `hyperref` these just behave like the `text...` version. The full list of `hyper...` formats is given in [Table 6.1 (Predefined Hyperlinked Location Formats)](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#tab:hyperxx) of the `glossaries` user manual, copied below:

- `hyperrm`    serif hyperlink
- `hypersf`    sans-serif hyperlink
- `hypertt`    monospaced hyperlink
- `hyperbf`    bold hyperlink
- `hypermd`    medium weight hyperlink
- `hyperit`    italic hyperlink
- `hypersl`    slanted hyperlink
- `hyperup`    upright hyperlink
- `hypersc`    small caps hyperlink
- `hyperemph`  emphasized hyperlink

In general it's simpler to always use these formats instead of `textbf` etc as then you won't need to make any changes if you decided to add `hyperref`. (The `\hyper...` commands corresponding to these format values are designed specifically for locations, and shouldn't be used elsewhere in the document.)