# gls option breaking hyperref howto combine options with hyperref

Tags: hyperref, glossaries

```
\glsadd{arts:BouguereauLeGuepier}
```

works just fine, but if I try to mark the main entry I lose the hyperlink in the PDF. Guess I am just using the format option wrong but after about half an hour searching manual and Google I am now just asking...

```
\glsadd[format={textbf}]{arts:BouguereauLeGuepier}
```

how do I use the format option correctly without breaking hyperref linking it to the page from the glossary?

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: See [glossaries format removing hyperlink](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394987).

Comment: autsch... that hurts. That is my exactly same question. That explains why I had the bad feeling I would looks pretty stupid if I do not find the answer... If you make the comment an answer I'll be happy to mark it solved...

Comment: @ErikItter It's okay. I can mark it as a duplicate. (I don't like to do that without commenting first as I have a gold badge for `glossaries`, which means that the question will be instantly closed rather than a vote to close.)

Comment: thx, do that. still embarassing (i had a strange de javu feeling but it did not made it turn up the memory that you guys allready helped me to solve exactly that problem with last year's diary. now I made one bold for every term, think I cannot forget again :) )...